# How to escape unicode characters to symbol entitiy names in python?

Tags: python, escaping

What I want to achieve is

```
Í -> &iacute;
ø -> &oslash;
ñ -> &ntilde;
...
```

Is there a standard way for this in python or do I have to create my own dictionary and use it to escaape the characters manually?

I found a lot of hints for the other way around here on SO but none which answers my querstion.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean [HTML 4 entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [htmlentitydefs](http://docs.python.org/library/htmllib.html#module-htmlentitydefs):

```
In [217]: import htmlentitydefs

In [224]: ['&'+htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name[ord(x)]+';' for x in u'Íøñ']
Out[224]: ['&Iacute;', '&oslash;', '&ntilde;']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import htmlentitydefs

def EscapeUnicode(character):
    return "&%s;" % htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name[ord(character)]
```